# How to tell what libraries a piece of software needs?

Tags: server, games, 15.04, libraries

I'm using Ubuntu Server 15.04 and mainly running this to get a steam TF2 server going.

How can I tell what prerequisites I need to install to ensure this program will work?

This is the program

wget https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/client/installer/steamcmd_linux.tar.gz

Answer (score 0):

According to the [wiki](https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/SteamCMD#Downloading_SteamCMD) SteamCMD depends on `lib32gcc1` and `lib32stdc++6`. So:

> `sudo apt-get install lib32gcc1 lib32stdc++6`

should install theses packages.